# Access violation when writing struct to file

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a "book" struct containing the author, name and count of available books.

```
struct book {
    TCHAR author[32];
    TCHAR name[32];
    SHORT count;
    void insert() {
        cout << "Book author: "; wscanf_s(L"%s", author, _countof(author));
        cout << "Book name: "; wscanf_s(L"%s", name, _countof(name));
        cout << "Book count: ";  wscanf_s(L"%i", count);
    }
    void get() {
        cout << "Book info: " << endl;
        wprintf(L"\nAuthor - %s", author);
        wprintf(L"\nName - %s", name);
        wprintf(L"\nCount - %i", count);
        cout << endl;
    }
};
```

The task has me make a DAT file, and then add "books" inside it.

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(_TEXT("C:\\Students\\book.dat"), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
SetFilePointer(hFile, 0, 0, FILE_END);
book newBook;
DWORD bytesWritten;
newBook.insert();
WriteFile(hFile, &newBook, sizeof(book), &bytesWritten, NULL);
FindClose(hFile);
```

However, whenever I do this, I get an error:

> Access violation writing location 0xFFFFFEFE.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You really should be checking the return values from _all_ of those API calls to make sure that things are working.

Comment: Beyond the scanf error you do do error checking, you use TCHAR which is long obsolete, you use raw Win32 IO rather than C++ IO and write an uninitialized struct.

Comment: I am supposed to be using raw Win32 methods whenever possible. I wouldn't be using these if I had a choice. Will add error checking.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
cout << "Book count: ";  wscanf_s(L"%i", count);
```

should be

```
cout << "Book count: ";  wscanf_s(L"%i", &count);
```

You should probably also check that the file opened:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(_TEXT("C:\\Students\\book.dat"), GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
    cerr << "Unable to open file\n";
    exit(1);
}
```

--- Edit ---

With your code as-is Visual Studio gives the following warnings:

> c:\dev\test\test.cpp(14): warning C4477: 'wscanf_s' : format string '%i' requires an argument of type 'int *', but variadic argument 1 has type 'SHORT *'
>
> c:\dev\test\test.cpp(14): note: consider using '%hi' in the format string

What this means is that

```
cout << "Book count: ";  wscanf_s(L"%i", &count);
```

should be

```
cout << "Book count: ";  wscanf_s(L"%hi", &count);
```

or you should make count a DWORD.

Comment: Changed, added. Now reads: First-chance exception at 0x77D22312 (ntdll.dll) in SysLab4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0xFEFEFF1E.

Comment: Are you ignoring the compiler warnings or do you not have the Output window open?

Comment: Changed count to DWORD. Still getting access violations...the compiler only warns about signed/unsigned mismatch in lines 105 and 121, and conversion to SHORT in 122. [Full code here](http://pastebin.com/yTYeav8d).

Comment: VCib, at this point you're moving the goal post. Recommend a making a new question with [a minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That or fire up the debugger that came with your development environment and [start debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

The access violation is because you're calling `FindClose` on a handle opened with `CreateFile`. `FindClose` is only for closing handles obtained via `FindFirstFile`.

You need to call `CloseHandle` instead.